# Permission denied with building angular-bazel-example with Bazel 0.21 on Windows

Tags: bazel

I am consistently seeing an error when I try to execute `bazel run //src:devserver` in the angular-bazel-example project.

I am using Windows 10. I haven't been able to find anything that fixes this. I thought the issue might be related to `patch` or to the path being too long. However, I've used MSYS2 to install `patch`, I've changed the output directory using the option `--output_user_root`, and I've tried using a DOS prompt with admin privileges. Nothing seems to help.

The error message

```
INFO: SHA256 (https://codeload.github.com/golang/tools/zip/3e7aa9e59977626dc60433e9aeadf1bb63d28295) = 2384fa91351a7414b643c5230422ce45f5aa2be8a82727609afd4e64e6973a30
ERROR: Analysis of target '//src:devserver' failed; build aborted: no such package '@org_golang_x_tools//go/gcexportdata': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/temp/vvsv3266/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl", line 55
            patch(ctx)
    File "C:/temp/vvsv3266/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl", line 82, in patch
            fail(("Error applying patch %s:\n%s%s...)))
Error applying patch @io_bazel_rules_go//third_party:org_golang_x_tools-gazelle.patch:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/processes-jni.cc(383): CreateProcessW("C:\msys64\usr\bin" -c "patch '-p1' < C:/temp/vvsv3266/external/io_bazel_rules_go/third_party/org_golang_x_tools-gazelle.patch"): Access is denied.
INFO: Elapsed time: 691.367s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (484 packages loaded, 20777 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (484 packages loaded, 20777 targets configured)
Fetching @ngdeps; fetching 245s
Fetching @org_golang_x_tools; Patching repository 15s
```

Can someone please tell me how to remedy this?

Comment: Hello, did you find some kind of answer about that ? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. I ended up giving up - I was researching whether using Bazel would be feasible for my company. Also at the time, the example project build was failing. If it's stable now, maybe one of the team would respond to the question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'll put that aside for a while :)

Comment: How did you set `--output_user_root` for ng serve? Or are you using bazel directly. I cannot find ANYTHING on this (I have a space in my user directory name)

Comment: I managed to set `output_user_root` sort of indirectly with `set username=simon` (because it was otherwise adding a space). However I've apparently now been screwing around with this for 3 hours and got nowhere. I keep getting ` Compiling Sass failed` and `Querying for files to watch... )) was unexpected at this time.` and `'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command`